# MySQL HAVING Gives Me Different Result

Tags: mysql

I have this data :

```
+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
| timestamp          | profit_loss | profit_loss_type |
+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
| lm58-1527906222477 |  0.00200000 | profit           |
| lm58-1527906222477 | -0.00008617 | fraction         |
| lm58-1527906222477 | -0.00027400 | normal           |
| lm58-1527906222477 |  0.00008617 | nett             |
| lm58-1527906222477 |  0.00027400 | nett             |

| lm99-1527906222888 |  0.00200000 | profit           |
| lm99-1527906222888 | -0.00008617 | fraction         |
| lm99-1527906222888 | -0.00027400 | normal           |

| lm11-1527906222999 |  0.00200000 | profit           |
| lm11-1527906222999 |  0.00008617 | fraction         |
| lm11-1527906222999 |  0.00027400 | normal           |

+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

and I want to get `timestamp` WITH `profit_loss < 0` but WITHOUT HAVING `profit_loss_type = 'nett'`

so I'm expecting result like this :

```
+--------------------+
| timestamp          |
+--------------------+
| lm99-1527906222888 |
+--------------------+
```

here's my query to get all `timestamp` that contains `profit_loss < 0` :

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM gross_profit
WHERE profit_loss < 0
AND (profit_loss_type = 'normal' OR profit_loss_type = 'fraction')
GROUP BY timestamp

13367 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

but when I add `HAVING`, why the result is different?

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM gross_profit
GROUP BY timestamp
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN profit_loss_type = 'nett' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN profit_loss < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;

10741 rows in set (0.23 sec)
```

while on this simulation, I only have 1 timestamp that contains `profit_loss_type = nett`, so the result should be 13366. not 10741.

Comment: Can you share some more sample data and reduce it properly? Your given example shows two rows with `profit_loss_type = nett`, and with the given data it looks impossible to get about 10k result rows

Comment: my real data is about 60k rows. it's already reduced and I tried to simplify the problem. I just need to get `timestamp` with minus `profit_loss` but doesn't contains `profit_loss_type = nett`

Comment: the second condition should be  `SUM(CASE WHEN profit_loss < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;`

Comment: Also the querys are different. The first one use `WHERE`  to filter the data ***BEFORE*** the `group by` the second one use `HAVING` to filter ***AFTER*** the `group by`, anyway based on your question you want the second version.

Comment: In the first Query you're asking '**Profit_loss greater than 0**'. In the second query you're asking '**profit_loss is exact one**'.
In addition the first query is comparing the **value** and the second is comparing the **sum of appearances**.
Both queries are not comparable.

Maybe it will help to inverse the result (change SUM()=0 to SUM()=1) to see the 2626 results and understand why they are not shown.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : you're right. this works : `SUM(CASE WHEN profit_loss < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to SUM > 0

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce44c4/4)**

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM gross_profit
GROUP BY timestamp
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN profit_loss_type = 'nett' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN profit_loss < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```